# How to pass CSVReader object as call by value instead of call by reference in java?

Tags: java, csv, file, fileinputstream, opencsv

Java is a Call By Value but when I am passing CSVReader object it is working as a Call by reference.

```
private CSVReader csvReader=null;
    public String getColumn(String filePath, String tagValue, int inputColumn, int outputColumn) throws Exception {
        if(csvReader == null){
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
            csvReader= new CSVReader(fileReader);
        }
        return fileReader(csvReader, tagValue, inputColumn, outputColumn);
    }

    private String fileReader(CSVReader csvReader1, int tagValue, int inputIndex, int outputIndex) throws Exception  {
        String[] value = csvReader1.readNext();

        while ((value = csvReader1.readNext()) != null) {
            String inputColumnValue = value[inputIndex];
            String ouputColumnValue = value[outputIndex];
            if(isNullOrEmpty(inputColumnValue) && isNullOrEmpty(ouputColumnValue))
                if(inputColumnValue.equals(tagValue))
                    return ouputColumnValue;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For example:
Input file contains:

```
a1, b1, c1
a2, b2, b3
a3, b3, c3
```

let say, i am calling fileReader like this:

```
getColumn(input file, "a3", 0, 2);
```

Then, it will return c3 as output.
If i call it again like this:

```
getColumn(input file, "a3", 0, 2);
```

Then, it will return exception.
because csvReader passing as a call by reference not call by value.
First, when getColumn called csvReader pointing to 0th row.
But after processing when i will call it again it will be on N+1 row.
So, it will return exception.

Any Solution to reuse getColumn().

Comment: Your problem is not related to pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. It is about a Reader cannot be read twice. It is a single pass through process. If you only want to read it once and query a lot, you have to load the content into an data structure and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Params are always passed by value in Java. The problem that you have is that the value is actually a reference to a real object which is situated in heap memory.
In your case a new instance of csvReader has to be created whenever `getColumn` method is called.

```
public String getColumn(String filePath, String tagValue, int inputColumn, int outputColumn) throws Exception {
        
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
        CSVReader csvReader= new CSVReader(fileReader);
        
        return fileReader(csvReader, tagValue, inputColumn, outputColumn);
    }
```

Having `filePath` as an input param is another reason why you have to create new csv instance every time.
Nobody can guarantee you that the second call will be with the same path.

Another issue that I find here is this part:

```
if(isNullOrEmpty(inputColumnValue) && isNullOrEmpty(ouputColumnValue))
                if(inputColumnValue.equals(tagValue))
                    return ouputColumnValue;
```

If `inputColumnValue` is null or empty then there is no much sense to ask is `inputColumnValue.equals(tagValue)`. Especially if it’s NULL then you'll get NullPointerException.

Here is one example how to read all data from CSV (notice reader closing part)

```
public List<String[]> readAll(Reader reader) throws Exception {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = csvReader.readAll();
    reader.close();
    csvReader.close();
    return list;
}
```

If your csv is not too big maybe you can read csv content once and then every next time iterate through the list instead of opening csv over and over.

Comment: Hi @Master Yoda , I have created FileReader as global because I don't want to read the file again & again. And created CSVReader as local. But it is also not working. Again same issue.

Comment: Hi Krishna, instantiating new reader instance every time should solve the problem. Maybe you still have a problem because you're not closing readers (just guessing). I'll update my answer with one small example